# Things to do with young children in Paris in August

Tags: children, paris

I will be going to Paris in August with 3 other adults and 3 children (aged 2 to 6).

What kind of things are worth seeing/doing that will keep them amused? I would like options for if the weather is good or bad and ideally away from the usual tourist traps.

2 adults and 2 children only speak English, the others speak English and French.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the weather permits, you could do the following:

- Sailing a model in the pond at the jardin de Tuileries close to the louvre museum

[image: Children sailing a model at the Tuileries garden Source: WikiCommons]

- Row a boat in [Bois de Bologne](http://g.co/maps/mtqw7)
- Stroll along and have breakfast at at the [Cité Internationale Universitaire](http://ciup.fr/). It is a campus for international students, with a great atmosphere. You can have breakfast, brunch or lunch at the main building
- Visit one or more of the many parks (Jardin du Luxembourg, [Parc Montsouris](http://www.paris-walking-tours.com/parcmontsouris.html))
- In the Parc Montsouris there is also a puppet theatre, but I never managed to visit it due to irregular opening hours.

  When the weather is bad, you are a bit more limited. You could visit the  [Catacombes of Paris](http://g.co/maps/q95zv). It is an impressive underground system where millions of skeletons are stored. I would go there with my small kids, but I know parents who wouldn't.

Finally I could recommend all the cliche's. Children might relate to the Notre Dame if they have seen the Hunchback of the Notre Dame. You could watch [Amelie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am%C3%A9lie) and go to the Sacre Coeur afterwards.

Paris, in my opinion, is one the nicest cities for young and old. So do enjoy

Answer (score 4):

The thing that comes to mind first is [Disney Land Paris](http://us.disneylandparis.com/index.xhtml).  I know it's not Orlando but it'll be fun.

There is also a whole slew of items like:

- [Museum of Science and Industry](http://www.cite-sciences.fr/en/cite-des-sciences/)
- [The Zoo](http://goparis.about.com/od/parksgardensandsquares/ss/menagerie.htm)
- [Wax Museum](http://www.grevin.com/home)

Found all of above in [Go Paris About.com](http://goparis.about.com/od/sightsattractions/tp/VisitingPariswithkids.htm)

Now interestingly enough there is a website dedicated to visiting [France with family](http://www.france4families.com/paris/KidsFavouritesParis.htm).

There is also a [list of Top Attractions on Frommer's](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/paris/0062021105.html).  You might have to do a little research on what is actually in each one and find ones appropriate for your kids.

Comment: Wax Museum is really disappointing and quite expensive (22€ for adults, 15 for children from 6 to 14, free for children under 6).
With young xchildren if the weather is good, I'd suggest to see the Eiffel Tower, but from the Champ de Mars: it's on the less crowded side and children can play in the grass just in front of the Eiffel Tower.

Answer (score 2):

The Paris Tourist Office has its own [great 10 ideas](http://en.parisinfo.com/what-to-do-in-paris/info/guides/family-outings-in-paris/10-fabulous-family-outings-in-paris/10-fabulous-family-outings-in-paris) of what to do with children.

The first answer about the Catacombes reminded me of the sewers of Paris ([Égouts de Paris](http://en.parisinfo.com/paris-museum-monument/71499/Musee-des-egouts-de-Paris)) - this is a surprisingly interesting visit which I did with my children who were about 6 and 9 at the time.